# Running AMD64 packages on ARMhf, which solutions?

Tags: pi-4

I am new to Pi and my project is to be able to store some cryptos using software wallets (such as Coinomi or Atomic wallet) in order to avoid exchanges.

I tried with Atomic Wallet and the result when
`sudo dpkg -i package.deb` is `Package architecture (amd64)does not match system (armhf)`

So I tried to add architecture by
`sudo dpk --add-architecture amd64`and
`sudo apt-get update`

The results of the update is that `Skipping acquire of configured file "main/binary-amd64/Packages" as repository "http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspian bullseye InRelease" doesn't support architecture "amd64"`

*Is there a solution to this?*
I thought of changing the OS in Debian/Ubuntu but since it is the processor architecture, it would work, doesn't it?

I tried also Box86 but it doesn't seem to work neither.

*Does anyone have an idea or can explain what's going on and/or how to solve this ?*

Thank for your help

Comment: be careful not to lose a wallet to sd card corruption!

Answer (score 1):

I know no way of running Amd64 on a 32-bit kernel system. You'll need a different OS, be it a 64-bit Raspbian image, or a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu.

Once you have that running, you can try [Box64](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box64).

Comment: I put Ubuntu on my Pi and installed Box64. Box64 works. I see now that the problem is that I have .deb or . AppImage. The same problem occured mentioning the problem Package architecture (amd64) vs system (arm64).